# Pandas not fetching correct results from the data frame

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I am trying to query some data from a dataframe. The columns which I have to query are given in a particular .txt file. I stored the column headers from the .txt file but when I am querying the data from the data frame its not fetching the correct results.

When I fetch the query by mentioning '26-35' instead of the column header variable its giving me the correct results.

Can someone please let me know where I am going wrong.

```
f = open("testcaseprobability.txt")
no_test_cases=f.readline()

#for i in range(int(no_test_cases)):
read_age=f.readline()
read_age=str(read_age)
read_city_category=f.readline()
males=len(df[(df['Age']=='26-35') & (df['Gender']=='M')]) 
females=len(df[(df['Age']==read_age) & (df['Gender']=='F')])
higher_prob= males if males>females else females
print(males,females)

1460 0
```

Here is dataframe:

```
User_ID Gender  Age Occupation  City_Category   Stay_In_Current_City_Years  Marital_Status  Purchase
1000003 M   26-35   15  A   3   0   15227
1000005 M   26-35   20  A   1   1   5254
1000005 M   26-35   20  A       1   3957
1000005 M   26-35       A   1   1   6073
1000005 M   26-35   20  A   1   1   15665
1000015 M   26-35   7   A   1   0   19653
1000015 M   26-35   7   A   1   0   5958
1000015 M   26-35   7   A   1   0   11415
1000015 M   26-35   7   A   1   0   3594
1000015 M   26-35   7   A   1   0   4209
1000015 M   26-35   7   A   1   0   5407
1000015 M   26-35   7   A   1   0   7803
1000024 F   26-35   7   A   3   1   6940
```

Here is the datainsde the text file:

```
2
26-35
A
36-45
B
```

See the difference between the output of male and female. Its not fetching the count of female at all.

Comment: Try posting some data from the data-frame along with the expected output to make it easier to help.

Comment: The only difference lies on ```read_age```. It depends on what it is reading. Check that variable to see if it fits what you need, and check the dataframe to make sure they are the same

Comment: I just included some data for your reference. Hope it will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your read_age might contains a "\n" at the end.

This happens all the time with text files. =)